# converting daily to weekly on a daily basis

Tags: pandas, resampling

I have a daily pandas datarame of OHLC values.

I'm converting it into monthly values and weekly values using the following code :

```
def get_weekly(df):
    ohlc_dict = {
    'Open':'first',
    'High':'max',
    'Low':'min',
    'Close':'last',
    }
    df = df.resample('W-Fri').agg(ohlc_dict)
    return df

def get_monthly(df):
    ohlc_dict = {
    'Open':'first',
    'High':'max',
    'Low':'min',
    'Close':'last',
    }
    df=df.resample('M').agg(ohlc_dict)
    return df
```

The problem is that I would like to do it on a rolling basis, I want - on each day - the OHLC values for the previous month/week. Don't know how to do it, I tried with resample parameters but it does not work